# Twitter kit crash when authenticate again after cancel

Tags: android, authentication, twitter-fabric

I am using TwitterKit

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Here is how I call Twitter Authentication using TwitterAuthClient:

```
loginButtonTwitter = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
        loginButtonTwitter.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                mType = 3;
                // The TwitterSession is also available through:
                // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
                session = result.data;
                // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
                // with your app's user model
//                String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                LOGD(":: Name ::", session.getUserName());
                getUserData();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
                mType = 0;
            }
        });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                loginButtonTwitter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

If I press login button, then press back or cancel button to close authentication screen, then press login button again, it throws an exception without showing authentication screen again:

```
 01-17 12:01:06.216 3316-3316/com.app E/Twitter: Authorization completed with an error
                                                      com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
                                                          at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.handleAuthorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:110)
                                                          at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.authorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:101)
                                                          at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(TwitterLoginButton.java:161)
                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5382)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:928)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:723)
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027835/android-twitter-login-button-not-working

Comment: sorry it's not working for me!

Comment: Any another idea how to solve it?